# How to add content to a page when clicking on a link and then redirect to that page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When a certain image is clicked I want to add some content to a different page using `jQuery`. I have a generic page called `product.php` and on this page the content to be added depends on which image it is clicked on the home page `(home.php)`. On `product.php` I am trying to add the content on a div with the id of `#product`.

But when the image is clicked it redirects to the unmodified page of `product.php`. Is there a way to redirect to the `product.php` page after the wanted content is loaded?

```
$('.product img').click(function () {
    // it gives the right index         
    var index = $( ".product img" ).index( this ); 
    // it works well
    var myProduct = 'snippet-product'+ (index + 1)+'.php'; 
    $( "#product" ).load( myProduct ); 
    // it redirects  to the 'product.php' without the new content
    window.location.href = 'product.php'; 
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: You could append the url with some sort of parameter. Something like window.location.href = 'product.php' + '?param'

Comment: Do you want to load the content into the #product div AND navigate to another page?

Comment: Yes I would like to  load the content into to the specific #product div which is on product.php and then I would like to be redirected to the product.php page and to be able to see the content that was loaded

Comment: You don't need any javascript click handler or window.location.href to do this. How do the products get listed on home.php? Loaded from a database via PHP calls in a loop? During that loading it can build the links like `<a href="./product.php?productId=1234"><img src="1234.png"></a>` using the product name, id, image etc fetched from the DB. The product.php page then uses the productId to load _it's_ contents like Cyclopeus suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand your question but you need to redirect with a location like: `window.location.href = 'product.php?product=' + index;` as @lharby said, and then change your PHP code catching the `$_REQUEST["product"]` and make a `switch` or an `if` to show content based on `$_REQUEST["product"]` value.

---

Your "initial question" was:

- *Step 1.* Load content to a page.
- *Step 2.* Go to location product.php.

If you reload the page (or change the location), all your content loaded with jQuery disappears. Do you know what i mean?

I really don't know what you want.

Do you want only to change the URL but don't reload the page? Please explain a bit more what you want to acomplish.

Sorry for my English...

Comment: I have a list of images on my home page. When I click on any of them I need to be redirected to the product.php. The problem is that product.php is just a skeleton page and based on the index of the image that is clicked on I want to load a specific content on this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the specific product information to the 'product.php' page in the url as a query string:

```
window.location.href = 'product.php?index=' + index; // <-something like this
```

Then on you PHP use `$_GET['index']` to return the index of the product:

```
if (isset($_GET['index'])) 
    $productIndex = $_GET['index'];
```

Then use `$productIndex` in the PHP script to find and generate the appropriate content to display.